# Django Rest Framework: what happened to my default Renderer?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I would like calls to /contacts/1.json to return json, 1.api to return browsableAPI, and calls with format=None aka /contacts/1/ to return a template where we call render_form. This way end-users can have pretty forms, and developers can use the .api format, and ajax/apps etc use .json. Seems like a common use case but something isn't clicking for me here in DRF...

Struggling with how DRF determines the Renderer used when no format is given. I found and then lost some info here on stack exchange that basically said to split the responses based on format. Adding the TemplateHTMLRenderer caused all sorts of pain. I had tried to split based on format but that is giving me JSON error below.

I don't understand the de facto way to define what renderer should be used. Especially when no format is provided. I mean, it "just works" when using Response(data). And I can get the TemplateHTMLRenderer to work but at the cost of having no default Renderer.

GET /contacts/1/ Gives the error: 
`<Contact: Contact object> is not JSON serializable`

Using this code:

```
class ContactDetail(APIView):
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
queryset = Contact.objects.all()
renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer,)

"""
Retrieve, update or delete a contact instance.
"""
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Contact.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Contact.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    contact = self.get_object(pk)
    serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
    if format == 'json' or format == "api":
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({'contact': contact, 'serializer':serializer}, template_name="contact/contact_detail.html")
```

But  GET /contacts/1.json , 1.api, or 1.html ALL give me the correct output. So it seems that I have created an issue with the content negotiation for the default i.e. format=None

I must be missing something fundamental. I have gone through the 2 [tutorials](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and read the [Renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) docs but I am unclear on what I messed up here as far as the default. I am NOT using the DEFAULT_RENDERERS in settings.py, didn't seem to make a difference if in default or inside the actual class as shown above.

Also if anyone knows a way to use TemplateHTMLRenderer without needing to switch on format value, I'm all ears.

EDIT: IF I use

```
if format == 'json' or format == "api" or format == None:
    return Response(serializer.data)
else:
    return Response({'contact': contact, 'serializer':serializer},
```

Then I am shown the browsable API by default. Unfortunately, what I want is the Template HTML view by default, which is set to show forms for end users. I would like to keep the .api format for developers.

Comment: `content-type` is a secondary determinant.  Check out [this page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/)

Comment: @Ross Rogers From your link: "REST framework uses a simple style of content negotiation to determine which media type should be returned to a client, based on the available renderers, __the priorities of each of those renderers__, and the client's Accept: header." In this context, I believe I am asking about the priority of renderers. Forgive me if I am dense but I'm unsure how `content-type` comes into play. Maybe the url ending such as .json is what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

**TL; DR: Check the order of your renderers - they are tried in order of declaration until a content negotiation match or an error occurs.**

Changing the line

```
renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer, )
```

to

```
renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer, )
```

Worked for me. I believe the reason is because the content negotiator starts at the first element in the renderer classes tuple when trying to find a renderer. When I have `format==None`, I'm thinking there is nothing else for DRF to go on, so it assumes I mean the "default" which seems to be the first in the tuple.

EDIT: So, as pointed out by @Ross in his answer, there is also a global setting in the settings.py for the project. If I remove my class level `renderer_classes` declaration and instead use this in settings.py

```
# ERROR
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (    
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
    )
}
```

Then I get a (different) JSON error. However, as long as 
            'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer', 
is not listed first, for example:

```
 # SUCCESS, even though JSON renderer is checked first
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',        
    'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
)
```

**So if we hit BrowsableAPIRenderer before we try TemplateHTMLRenderer then we get an error - whether or not we are relying on renderer_classes or DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES**. I imagine it passes through JSONRenderer gracefully but for whatever reason BrowsableAPIRenderer raises an exception.

So I have simplified my view code after analyzing this...

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        contact = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
        if format == None:
            return Response({'contact': contact, 'serializer':serializer}, template_name="contact/contact_detail.html")        
        else:
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

..which better reflects what I was originally trying to do anyway.

Comment: You'll have to add that field for each view.  If you set the defaults, wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: You're right as long as the majority of my view classes need to act that way, but most of them probably won't. My starting point yesterday was: Everything except contacts works how I want, how do I get a simple form into the mix for the contacts? Either way, the issue comes down to passing data to BrowsableAPIRenderer before trying TemplateHTMLRenderer

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the source code, the *priority* seems to be the order of the renderers specified in the `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` parameter in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
    )
}
```

So, if you specify a bunch of renderer classes, the first renderer that is valid will be selected based on if it is valid for the request given the `.json/.api/.html` extension and the `Accept:`  header *(not `content-type`, as I said in the comment on your question)*.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it, I agree that  "the priority seems to be the order of the renderers specified in the DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES parameter in settings.py". I was solving it a different way as you were answering, with renderer_classes reordering. Btw, for my purpose the  DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES didn't need to be declared. I was able to make it work with either your approach, or renderer_classes approach.

Comment: Great!  I agree both will work.  However, doing it in `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` will do it in one place.  Otherwise you'll have to set `renderer_classes` in each APIView.  Anyways, glad you're over the hurdle.