# Django Rest Framework Response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, response

I'm studying Django Rest Framework. I understand what is Django content negotiation, and the use of the Response function. In an example I've seen a code like:

```
def func(request):
if request.method == "GET":
queryset_objects = //
serializer = FooSerializer(queryset_objects, many = True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

This function will render a JSON. But the only parameter passed to Response is a dictionary like type (serializer.data). How Render decide that the response must be a JSONN instead another type (without header)?

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37170157/9374673) and poke around in the REST Framework documentation on [content negotiation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/). Then maybe add some details on what is unclear about those explanations if you need further clarification.

Comment: I've read, but the only parameter passed to "Response()" is " serializer.data", that contain a dictionary key-value...not Accept header

Comment: The Accept header comes from the client, typically the browser of the person requesting the api endpoint. In the absence of specifying which renderers to use, rest framework uses the defaults specified in settings. If you don't specify in settings, the first default one is the JSONRenderer.